# How to know whether Ubuntu is installed in Win or next to Win?

Tags: system-installation, windows

How can I figure out how was a Ubuntu operating system installed, i.e., inside Windows or next to Windows, assuming I don't have any knowledge about the time of installation and the process undertaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two easy and dirty ways... When installed through windows, wubi will select windows as the default operating system, so in the GRUB menu it would appear as first. Another way is to look in the windows control panel, in the uninstall section. If ubuntu is one of the programs and is available to uninstall, it was installed through wubi.

As I understand wubi installs ubuntu in the same partition as the one in which windows is and you should be able to see this in a partition manager program(not from ubuntu itself, from a live session for example, or from windows). If there are multiple partitions on the disk (besides the system reserved created by windows and the proper windows one) ubuntu was installed next to windows.

Comment: The GRUB shows Ubuntu first. So I can be sure that it's installed alongwith Windows?

Comment: You can't be certain(the order can be changed on wubi config files), but there is a good chance. Check the windows control panel to be sure.